# Text doesn't appear in UITableViewCell (iOS7/Storyboard)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios7, storyboard

I'm trying to display some content in my `UITableView`. That's how I did it in my Storyboard :

[image]

In my code, I have created a parser and I pass it my `TableViewController`. And then :

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
{
    [myTVController.tableView reloadData];
}
```

And in my controller :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RSSLinksCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    RSSObject *obj = (RSSObject *)[links objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = obj.link;

    return cell;
}
```

But my cells keep being empty. What's even stranger is that I also tried it with iOS6 and it works well. And I tried to change the cell's `backgroundColor` and it worked too.
In the log I also tried to see if my `obj.link` text is empty or null but it's not.
So... I really don't know what to do. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you check if the tableview's datasource and delegate is set to that class?

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo Yes it is, as I'm using a UITableViewController it's automatically done and I just checked it again.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas, but what if you use `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]` method? Instead of the one with `forIndexPath`?

Comment: When you say you've tried it with iOS 6 - what is you changing when you move from one platform to the other? Just switching simulators? Or do you have a separate iOS 6 project/XIB?

Comment: Just switching simulators. I tried it also @EnricoSusatyo and it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Is the `textLabel` outlet the one that's being displayed? You haven't added any additional `UILabel` instances to the cell? And if you check the value of `cell.textLabel`, is it definitely non-nil?

Comment: One more shot in the dark. What if you change the Table View Cell style to `Custom` instead of `Basic`? I really am running out of ideas. If that doesn't solve it, maybe try putting a sample project demonstrating this problem on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RSSLinksCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"RSSLinksCell"];
    }

    RSSObject *obj = (RSSObject *)[links objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = obj.link;

    return cell;
}
```